# partition on flash storage via ADB shell

Tags: adb, internal-storage, tablet, partitions

I want to make a FAT 32 partition on unmontable flash because I did something wrong that I can get mount agaim the internal SD of my tablet. So I start with (in ubuntu environment)

```
adb shell
cd ./dev/block/vold
```

then with ls command I see as result

```
93:64
93:65
```

if I put

```
parted /dev/block/vold/93:64
```

I get the warning

```
/system/bin/sh: parted: not found
```

how can I make the parted command to work?. My further intention is to identify which of  93:64 or 93:65 is pointing to my flash storage and then I want to format this to FAT 32. Please, help.

Comment: Have you installed parted binary to begin with? First of all, does your Android have root access? Which device and Android version is it?

Comment: I have root acces because I see root@android:/ #, the Android version is 4.0.3   also, with the command # cat /proc/partitions I get:    
    93        0      16384 nanda
    93        8      16384 nandb
    93       16      32768 nandc
    93       24     409600 nandd
    93       32     524288 nande
    93       40      16384 nandf
    93       48      32768 nandg
    93       56     262144 nandh
    93       64    6470656 nandi
    93       65    5421056 nandi1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal SD was unable to be mounted (indeed it was mounted but 0 bytes of memory) because it had errors made by me when I try to make a partition on it. I solve the problem easily, I got a external SD and I deleted its format in Gparted, then I put this in my device, a message popup showed if I want to repair it, click yes and Eureka !! my internal SD was repaired too. It seems that android device checked and repaired every SD card type in it and I get back my internal SD with its original 5 Gb !!!!.

Coool !!!